# Unable to comment on my web-app

Tags: php

I am working on a small CMS-like project and all the posts posted from the user gets displayed on a page which I have named as **news_feed.php**. And the page **news_feed.php** looks like this:

```
<?php
require '../includes/header.php'; //It contains the header of the page.

function get($property){
  require '../includes/backbone.php'; //It contains the server information
  $connection = mysqli_connect($server_name, $database_username, $database_password, $database_name);
  $sql = "SELECT * FROM users WHERE id = '" . $_SESSION["id"] . "'";
  $result = mysqli_query($connection, $sql);
  while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)){
    $outcome = $row[$property];
  }
  return $outcome;
}




function showPosts($date, $author, $type, $body, $comments, $id) {
  ?>
  <div class="post">
    <div class="poster"><a href="user.php/<?php echo $author ?>"> <b id="author"><?php echo $author . " posted a new " . $type . ""; ?></a></b> <b id="date"> <?php echo $date ?> </b></div>
    <div class="body"><p><?php echo $body ?></p></div>
    <?php
    if($type === "query"){
        enableComment();
        if(isset($_POST["postComment"]) && !empty($_POST["comment"])){
        postComment(get("full_name"), date("h:ma"), $_POST["comment"], $id);
    }
    }
    ?>
    <form action="<?php echo htmlspecialchars($_SERVER["PHP_SELF"]); ?>" method="post">
     <button id="showComments" name="showComments"><i class="fa fa-sort-desc"></i> Show comments</button>
      </form>
    <div class="comments">
      <?php
      if(isset($_POST["showComments"])){
        echo $comments;
      }
      ?>
    </div>
  </div>

<?php
function enableComment() {
  ?>
  <form action="<?php echo htmlspecialchars($_SERVER["PHP_SELF"]); ?>" method="post">
  <input name="comment" type="text" placeholder="Wanna Help?" id="comment">
  <button name="postComment" type="submit" id="commentButton"><i class="fa fa-paper-plane"></i></button>
    </form>
    <?php
}


function postComment($author, $time, $comment, $id){
  require '../includes/backbone.php'; //Server Info!!!
  $connection = mysqli_connect($server_name, $database_username, $database_password, $database_name);
  $sql = "UPDATE posts SET comments = \"'" . $author . "' -> '". $comment . "' @ '".$time . "'\" WHERE id = ". $id. "";
  mysqli_query($connection, $sql);
}

require '../includes/backbone.php'; //Server Info!
$connection = mysqli_connect($server_name, $database_username, $database_password, $database_name);
$sql = "SELECT * FROM posts";
$result = mysqli_query($connection, $sql);
while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)){
    showPosts($row["posted_date"], $row["author"], $row["type"], $row["body"], $row["comments"], $row["id"]); //Main function to run
}

?>
```

Everything works fine and all the posts get shown, and if the type of the post is *query*, the comment box and the comment button appears. The only thing that is not working is: whenever I try to comment on a post, The comment gets commented to all other posts as well. The id gets looped over and the comment gets commented to all the posts.
I have tried a lot of things like:

- Using break statement, but it breaks the whole process and nothing gets shown.
- Using exit(); but it terminates the whole
  program.
- Getting id after the button is clicked and then commenting
  the comment.

But, nothing just works. Please help me to sort out this problem.

Comment: since it's a function you can try return false; or you can just unset your $id after you used it

Comment: return doesn't work either.... And I didn't get your 'id' thing. Would you mind explaining it?

Comment: you can set $id to null after the comment was posted

Comment: ohh, I will surely try that!

Comment: How would I do that?? **$id = null; at the last line???** It didn't work...

Comment: There's a lot of code to read here.  Removing the CSS makes it a little easier to follow.

Comment: Do you have many comments per post?  What does $comments look like?

Answer (score 0):

You are looping through all your comments, and if there is a http post from your comment form, you are posting a comment for every post:

Pseudo code of your current flow:

```
loop through all posts:
    if post comment form submitted:
        post comment (user name, date, comment, post id).
```

(See your main loop (select * from posts) this calls showPosts and postComment for every iteration.)

To fix you could add the post id to your comment form (for the correct association) and remove your comment processing from your show posts function - handling it elsewhere.

You are mixing responsibilities in your functions, which makes following the code difficult.  Clearly separate your comment posting and processing code from your comment showing code.

You are also inserting raw unfiltered values into your database.  Please use prepared statements.

I can't quite fathom how your comments relate to your posts.  Your postComment function uses an SQL UPDATE, rather than an INSERT, do you have one comment per post?  If you want to add multiple comments to each post, you may want to create a separate comments table.